# pygame-'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

This code prints a "hit" message when circle-a and circle-b collide.

But when I run it, I get the error "'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute'rect'".

What's the problem? (I assume and assume that circle-a and circle-b are not images or surfaces, but just shapes.)

```py
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 800))

ax=100
ay=400
bx=500
by=400

while 1:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    ax+=1
    bx-=1
    a=pg.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,225], [ax, ay], 10)
    b=pg.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,0], [bx, by], 10)

    if pg.sprite.collide_circle(a,b):
        print("hit")

    pg.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

[`pygame.sprite.collide_circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) is meant for the use with [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) objects.

In the statement:

```py
if pg.sprite.collide_circle(a,b):
```

`a` and `b` are [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects. Hence `a` and `b` are illegal arguments for `pygame.sprite.collide_circle()`.

Write a function which evaluates if e circles are intersecting.

Compute the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) beteween the center points of the circle. And test if the distance between the center points is less than the sum of the radii of the circles:

```py
import math
```

```py
def collide_circle(c1, r1, c2, r2):
    dist = math.hypot(c1[0]-c2[0], c1[1]-c2[1])
    return dist < r1+r2
```

```py
if collide_circle(a.center, a.width/2, b.center, b.width/2):
    print("hit")
```

or get the center points and the radii in the function directly from the `pygame.Rect` objects:

```py
def collide_circle(c1, c2):
    r1, r2 = c1.width/2, c2.width/2
    dist = math.hypot(c1.centerx-c2.centerx, c1.centery-c2.centery)
    return dist < r1+r2
```

```py
if collide_circle(a, b):
    print("hit")
```

---

See the example:

```py
import pygame as pg
import math 

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 800))

ax, ay = 100, 400
bx, by = 500, 400

def collide_circle(c1, c2):
    r1, r2 = c1.width/2, c2.width/2
    dist = math.hypot(c1.centerx-c2.centerx, c1.centery-c2.centery)
    return dist < r1+r2

while 1:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    ax+=1
    bx-=1

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    a=pg.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,225], [ax, ay], 10)
    b=pg.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,0], [bx, by], 10)

    if collide_circle(a, b):
        print("hit")

    pg.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead.@Rabbid76 has mentioned the reason for the error.

```
if (math.sqrt((a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2))< 20:
    print("hit")
```

**Edit**

You can use the following fuction.

```
def check_collision(circle1, circle2):
    if (math.sqrt((circle1.x-circle2.x)**2 + (circle1.y-circle2.y)**2)) <= (circle1.size[0] + circle2.size[0])/2:
        return True
    return False
```

And then

```
if check_collision(a, b):
    print("hit")
```

Comment: 10 is the radius of the circle. Hence it has to be `< 2*10` rather then  `< 10`

Comment: Again it is wrong, because `circle1.size[0]` is the width of the surrounding rectangle. this is the diameter of the circle rather than the radius.

Comment: I'm sorry.Corrected it.Thanks.Its perfect now

Comment: This works but it could be better. You could take advantage of the `math.hypot()` function instead of expanding it. It is both simpler and it's likely that the hypot function is coded in C and so would be more efficient than the expanded version in python, and this collision code will be executed a lot. Also it is not clear why you are using `circle1.size[0]` rather than `circle1.width`.@Rabbid76's `collide_circle(c1, c2)` version is cleaner.